# How to show GlyphButton in FMX ListView

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

On Delphi 10.4.2. This is a very simple question.
A new multi-device project, Add Listview onto the form. Toggle to design mode, use DynamicAppearance.
Add 2 text items and 1 glyphButton (Checkbox),Hook up a datasource.

At design time, no checkbox showing although Glyphbotton.visible is true. At run-time, coded a ListView1ItemClick even with single line code

`AItem.Objects.GlyphButton.Visible:=true;`

When click an item, it produces error as show in photo.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXtEf.png)

Any idea how to show the checkbox when user clicks an item. It should be a very simple function, why cannot even google an answer for this?

The sample code is on github https://github.com/tanghzuk/ListView-Test

Answer (score 1):

Afer enable the ToogleEditMode change your ListViewItem ItemAppearance to Custom.

You can show and hide the checkbox :

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ItemClick(const Sender: TObject; const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
  AItem.Objects.GlyphButton.Visible:= not AItem.Objects.GlyphButton.Visible;
end;
```

All the info are on the docwiki : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Customizing_FireMonkey_ListView_Appearance#Customizable_Item_Appearances

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried your way, it does not work. Please could you check the code on githut https://github.com/tanghzuk/ListView-Test.git to see where went wrong.  Basically , I want to achieve the effect in the sample of ListViewCheckList but with a DynamicAppearance as I need several ItemText s in one Item.

Comment: The ToogleEditMode isn't active, right click on your ListView and active it

Comment: Yes, it works but the check box is Leading. Tried to changed it to tailing it doesn't work. If you can toggleDesignMode without Editmode, you can see the glyphbutton position. The run time lay out is different from the design time? Any idea?  thanks

Comment: Thats not the question you ask, edit it and be more clear

Comment: I updated the code which is similar to my project. It has 4 ItemText, 1 glyphbutton in DynamicAppearance. How to make that glyphbutton work when user click an item? Your ToggleEditMode solution only works for 1 ItemText and 1 glyphbutton. I cannot customise to my own needs. thanks.

Comment: It work for more then if you want customize, do your own item with a TRectangle, TLayout, TText ..

Comment: thanks for your advice. that will be a lot of work, What EMBT do then? This should be a very simple function for a ListView. FMX has been a product for such a long time, they cannot even properly implement a glyphbutton?  What are they doing ?